# Getting Started with Azure: Worker Role

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I'm new to Azure.  I have a script that automatically installs Apache, Ruby, and configures both to run a basic Ruby on Rails project.  This script currently runs on Windows Server.

I'm now trying to get this working in Azure.  I've signed up for a subscription, and in Visual Studio I've opened a new Worker Role project.

I'm a little stuck now though.

1) Where should I place the installation files and project files (ruby, apache, etc)? 
2) Where is the best place to put the script?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a Visual Studio project, you have three places to get things up and running:

- Startup script. This runs before your workerrole.cs methods get called. It's ideal for installing software requiring elevated permissions, tweaking the registry, etc. For apache, there's no need for elevated permissions - it's just xcopy plus environment variables.
- workerrole.cs OnStart() - this handler gets called prior to your role instances being added to the load balancer. You can download your apache zip from blob storage, unzip to a local folder, get it started up.
- workerrole.cs Run() - same as OnStart() but your role instances are now in the load balancer. I wouldn't recommend setting up a web server here.

Things are a bit different when setting up tomcat from Eclipse, as there's no workerrole.cs. Instead, you have a startup script. Supplied with the Windows Azure plugin for Eclipse are several sample scripts: one for tomcat, one for JBoss, etc. You can then look at how those sample scripts setup the environment and launch the web server.

One bit of guidance: while you *can* package tomcat, ruby, and other runtime bits with your deployment, this also grows deployment size. I typically put 3rd-party bits in blob storage and then download them to my role instances at startup. This download is *extremely* fast. This also affords me the ability to update these bits without needing to redeploy (for instance: tomcat has already gone through a half-dozen incremental updates since I pushed up a deployment a few months ago; I just upload a new tomcat zip and recycle my role instances).